# AngularJS not allowing access to external functions via requireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm using [JS require()](http://requirejs.org/) to use functions in another JavaScript file. I keep hitting this error:

```
TypeError: lightFn.hextoRGB is not a function
    at lightPage.js:17
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16664)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16928)
    at done (angular.js:11266)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:11464)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11405)
```

I'm running AngularJS 1.5. Here's the backend JS code for the HTML page:

```
'use strict';
(function($) {
angular.module('careApp.lightPage', ['ngRoute', 'farbtastic'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/lightPage', {
    templateUrl: './lightPage/lightPage.html',
    controller: 'lightPageCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('lightPageCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    //require() call for external script, located in another folder
    var lightFn = require(['../client_scripts/lights/lights.js']);
    $scope.color = "#123456";
    //watches $scope.color for any changes. On change, run the function.
    $scope.$watch('$scope.color', function(){
        console.log("Sending " + $scope.color + " to lighting board.");
        lightFn.hextoRGB($scope.color);
    });
}]);
})(jQuery);
```

Based on the error I'm getting, I'm guessing that either:

- the `require()` that I wrote isn't working correctly
- something in AngularJS is preventing me from using `require()`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The brackets `[]` are not needed, is there an exports at in the `lights.js`?

Comment: @ryan0319 If the questioner is really using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), then the `[]` is needed.  This `require()` is different than the one node.js or any other commonjs spec fallows since it is AMD.

Comment: @zero298 You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you use `require()`.  `require()` accepts, two arguments, an `Array` of dependencies, and a `Function` to call with the loaded dependencies as arguments.

```
require([
    // Provide an array of dependencies you need
    "one/of/my/deps",
    "another/dep"
], function (
    // Your dependencies will be loaded into the arguments of your callback
    oneOfMyDeps,
    anotherDep
) {
    // Your dependencies are available here
    oneOfMyDeps.foo();
    anotherDep.bar();
});
```

You're trying to store the return value of the `require()` in `lightFn`.  However, `require()` doesn't really return anything useful in that respect.  You need to use do your operations with the loaded dependencies in the callback you give to `require()`.  You can see the correct usage below.

```
require(['../client_scripts/lights/lights.js'], function (lightFn) {
    $scope.color = "#123456";
    //watches $scope.color for any changes. On change, run the function.
    $scope.$watch('$scope.color', function () {
        console.log("Sending " + $scope.color + " to lighting board.");
        lightFn.hextoRGB($scope.color);
    });
});
```

---

It's also worth noting that AngularJS has a similar concept that AMD (require.js) uses with respect to **Dependency Injection**.  However, the signature is strangely different.  In fact, you are already using it in your current application.  Read about AngularJS' [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/lightPage', {
    templateUrl: './lightPage/lightPage.html',
    controller: 'lightPageCtrl'
  });
}])
```

In AngularJS, the signature is just an Array with the dependency strings in order followed by a `Function` that has arguments for the dependency objects.  Like I said, this is *very* similar to AMD, with the difference being that the callback is the last member of the dependency array.

```
app().config([
    // Deps are in array similar to AMD
    "some/dep",
    "some/other/dep",
    // Callback is last member of array
    function (
        // Dep objects are still arguments of callback
        someDep,
        someOtherDep
    ) {
        domDep.fizz();
        someOtherDep.buzz();
}]);
```

---

This is different from how [`require` in commonjs works](https://webpack.github.io/docs/commonjs.html#module-dependency).  In commonjs, `require()` actually returns something. If you're familiar with `node.js`, they share usage details.

The difference is that [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) implements the [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) JavaScript specification rather than the commonjs one, making it asynchronous so you don't necessarily have to wait for all your modules to load before you can do anything.  There are pros and cons to both, but that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: This definitely helps, but I am now getting another error outside the scope of my own question. I'll mark your answer as complete, though!